# Why does paper under pressure flatten over time?

Tags: everyday-life, home-experiment

If I have a crumpled paper I can put it under a heavy book. If I remove the book in a minute the paper will still be rather crumpled, but if I leave it on for a longer time it will flatten more.

But why? There is no movement involved, so where does the energy to flatten the paper come from?

Comment: It's kinda like putting a book on a spring (non-ideal) which compresses over time.

Comment: Note that this is just a guess: Could diffusion of ambient humidity be responsible for the delayed effect?

Comment: @HritikNarayan Exactly.

Comment: @engineer Kind of like this? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23485/113352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Practical Considerations for Humidifying and Flattening Paper" (2003)](http://cool.conservation-us.org/coolaic/sg/bpg/annual/v21/bp21-15.pdf) by Stephanie Watkins, a conservationist, has this to say about how to flatten paper (emphasis mine):

> The aim of humidification is to reintroduce moisture into the paper support to **relax the fibers**... Gravity and time, or
>   pressure and time, can be as effective, depending on the
>   relative humidity of the storage area. Curled paper that is
>   sturdy can be hung from flat clips, such as paper-protected
>   bull clips, and left over a short time to slowly uncurl
>   (e.g. panoramas, large blueprints, etc.). Protect the items
>   from dust and light exposure during this process as it may
>   take several weeks.
>   However, humidification **relaxes the paper in a faster
>   manner and fibers are less likely to be stressed**.

Thus:

- Paper becomes flat once the microscopic cellulose fibers in the paper relax.
- This process does not complete instantaneously upon application of a force, i.e. it takes time so the longer you leave it the flatter it becomes.
- The energy should be coming from the book lowering ever so slightly as the creases in the paper disappear.